# Using jquery 1.4 or javascript how would I target a specific link using a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML:**
I've attached a simplified example of the problem I'm facing:

```
<h2>Product2</h2>
<div id="products">

    <a class="my-product1" href="#"><span>my-product1<span></a>
    <a class="my-product2" href="#"><span>my-product2<span></a>
    <a class="my-product3" href="#"><span>my-product3<span></a>
    <a class="my-product4" href="#"><span>my-product4<span></a>
    <a class="my-product5" href="#"><span>my-product5<span></a>

</div>​
```

**Javascript:**
I'm already pulling myProduct from the page title and forcing lowercase. Next I'm attempting to remove this product from the group of links based on its class. Its quite possible this is jquery101 however I can't figure out how to add a class to a link using a variable to determine which class to select. In this example lets assume var myProduct = Product2

```
function removeProduct(myProduct){
    $("a.myProduct").addClass("display-none");
};
```

Also, I am still learning so if you have the time a Brief explination of why what i'm doing is wrong would go a long way. Thanks for your time!

Comment: jQuery 4.4 .... have you invented time travel ? [jQuery current release](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Current_Release)

Comment: @ManseUK I guess he meant 1.4...

Comment: @Andre I never like to guess ... he could have meant `Prototype` or `Dojo` .....

Comment: He's just advanced for his age !

Comment: Haha Thanks for the fix Andre. I missed that. Its 1.4.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply concat the class name to the selector string:

```
$("a."+variable)...
```

---

**Extra info as you requested:**

Don't use a class "display-none"... change it's name or use jQuery native code that hides elements(`hide`([docs](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)))

```
function removeProduct(myProduct){
    $("a." + myProduct).hide();
};
```

Changing css rules is with the `css`([docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/)) function:

```
function removeProduct(myProduct){
    $("a." + myProduct).css('display', 'none');
};
```

Adding class is with `addClass` function:

```
function removeProduct(myProduct){
    $("a." + myProduct).addClass('someClass');
};
```

Change `myProduct` and `removeProduct` names to more meaningful variable names:

```
function hideAnchorElement(className){
    $("a." + className).hide();        
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this Helps a lot and I understand it all. I must still be missing something though, my script still won't work. Would you mind having a look at my Jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/bms85/W4fAX/29/

Comment: @Bms85smb. Fixed [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W4fAX/30/). Couple of things. **1.** Check your code with jsLint. **2.** Don't use global variables(`myProduct` in your case is one).

Comment: Thank you very much! Would you mind explaining why you reordered the functions? and why re-ordering them made all the difference?

Comment: JSlint explained all the flaws. Thank yotu for pointing it out!

Comment: @Bms85smb. Actually there was another issue with spaces. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W4fAX/33/). I removed the spaces in my code. You can also use `$.trim(string)` like I did in the last fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

The `class` attribute / property is used as a generic selector - ie you can apply a class to multiple objects  ... the `id` attribute / property is used for specific selection - and are unique. I suggest you change your HTML to use `id`s instead of `class`s

Try something like :

```
function removeProduct(myProduct){
    $("a."+myProduct).css("display","none");
};
```

uses [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to change the `display` property to `none`

or

```
function removeProduct(myProduct){
    $("a."+myProduct).hide();
};
```

[.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) does the same thing as the `.css()` method does above

or

```
function removeProduct(myProduct){
    $("a."+myProduct).addClass("yourclass");
};
```

where `yourclass` is a class you want to apply to an element.

And may I suggest you take a look at [How jQuery works](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

```
function removeProduct(myProduct){
    $("a."+myProduct).addClass("display-none");
};
```

Separating the string selector from the variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to hide the link on click event

```
$(function(){
    $('#products a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide();
    });
});​
```

A fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyx3x/).